# Why am I getting segmentation fault [139]?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The title is pretty clear I think. 


I am trying to create a program that calculates a 3x3 linear system using determinants, but I am getting a segmentation fault. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int determinant(int n, int m, int det[m][n])
{
    int res;
    res = det[0][0]*det[1][1] - det[0][1]*det[1][0];
    return res;
}
int main(void)
{
    int arr[3][4], det[2][2], i, j, D; //Dx1, Dx2, Dx3
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("Eisagete tous suntelestes ths %dhs eksisoshs.", i+1);
        scanf("%d %d %d %d", &arr[i][0], &arr[i][1], &arr[i][2], &arr[i][3]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 2; i++)
        {
            det[i][j] = arr[i+1][j+1];
        }
    }
    D = arr[0][0]*determinant(2, 2, det);
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 2; i++)
        {
            det[i][j] = arr[i+1][j+((j == 1) ? 1 : 0)];
        }
    }
    D -= arr[0][1]*determinant(2, 2, det);
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 2; i++)
        {
            det[i][j] = arr[i+1][j];
        }
    }
    D += arr[0][2]*determinant(2, 2, det);
    printf("%d\n", D);
}
```

I am getting the error right after completing the first `for` loop in `main`.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to find out where the seg fault occurs?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention this in OP. I added it via edit. It occurs after the first for loop.

Comment: This isn't OK: `int determinant(int n, int m, int det[m][n])`

Comment: @Paul Griffiths: In what sense? What's not OK about it?

Comment: `for(j = 0; j < 2; i++)` be careful when copying and pasting code.

Comment: This was initially `int determinant(int det[][])` but caused me error "Type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete".

Comment: Your function can only calculate determinants of 2x2 matrices. `m` and `n` are confusing and unneeded. `int determinant(int det[2][2])` is enough.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for pointing that out.. I can't believe I haven't seen it for like an hour now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the block:

```
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 2; i++)
    {
        det[i][j] = arr[i+1][j+1];
    }
}
```

You increment `i` in both loops, and adding 1 more to it while reading from the array. So at `arr[i+1]` you are reading to far.

A segmentation fault basically means you are trying to read something you don't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud never do what you're doing by passing static array sizes `m` and `n` as function argument:

```
int determinant(int n, int m, int det[m][n])
```

Check https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html for info